# CSS scroll absolute vs relative

Tags: css, css-position, styling

The issue is documented in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sawaira/j62309fx/39/

Stabilizing iteration (90% done)

```
    <div style="height:100%; width:300px;float:right;border: 2px solid #0094ff;border-radius:5px">
        <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <div class="containerChart2">
                            <div class="headerChartControl">
                                <span>My Team(s):</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="filterHolder1" class="listControl">
                                 <form id="formUserListObject">
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="userSelection" id="{{id}}" onchange="checkBoxSelected(id,false)" class="css-checkbox"/>
    <label for="{{id}}" class="css-label">
        {{userName}}
    </label>

</form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                      <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <div class="containerChart2">
                            <div class="headerChartControl">
                                <span>Find Other Team(s):</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="contentSearch">
                                <!-- This is the HTML element that will be used to render the KeyLines component -->
                                <form id="formSearch" class="formSearch">
                                    <input type="search" id="searchBox" />
                                </form>

                                <!--label id="headervalue2">Search Results:</label-->
                                <div id="filterHolder2" class="listControl"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                    <td colspan="4">
                               <div class="headerChartControl">

                                       <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('loading-image').style.display ='block'" value="Show"/>

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('loading-image').style.display ='none'" value="Hide"/>
                            </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
 </div>
</div>

#formUserListObject {
        font-size: x-small;
    }

    #tab0 {
        top: 50px;
    }

    #page {
        display: none;
    }

    #loading-image {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;     
        left:50%;            
        z-index:1;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;


    }

    .overallDiv {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ff6a00;
    }

    .myDiv {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #b6ff00;
    }

    .formClass {
    }

    .listControl {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        border: 2px solid #0094ff;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .paddingControl {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .slider {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        background-color: #00ff90;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
        position:absolute;
        z-index: -1000;
        left: -1000px;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: -1px;
        border: 0;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
        padding-left: 20px;
        height: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 15px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 0;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
        background-position: 0 -15px;
    }

    label.css-label {
        background-image: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_845137eccd6f9ac2355055adf283a248.png);
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-labelMinus {
        padding-left: 20px;
        height: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 15px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 -15px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-labelMinus {
        background-position: 0 -15px;
    }

    label.css-labelMinus {
        background-image: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_845137eccd6f9ac2355055adf283a248.png);
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .headerChartControl {
        background-color: #9ed1f6;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
    }


    .contentSearch {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .listControl {
        border: 1px solid #0094ff;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .searchText {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .formSearch {

        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }

    input[type="search"] {
        background: white url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAMAAABhq6zVAAAAIVBMVEW/v7+/v78AAAC/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v79QUkolAAAAC3RSTlOLYAAJeoMjRhpOcbsbtd4AAABJSURBVHjaVc1JDsAgDATB9uAF8v8Hx0QcSN9KssZI5eClDj18PRsFlmlQDcfUGd6A3EgYP1xncQ+sa5qYOk9jRQt1Y0izhU5bL2o2AW3ZQKeJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) 10px 6px no-repeat;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #0094ff;
        width: 100%;
    }


input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
        -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
    }
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
      -webkit-appearance: searchfield-decoration;
    }
```

1) If you click on the "checkbox" on the very right, you will notice the div scrolls to the left. I know this is happening because I have "position:absolute" in the style for the checkbox.

However, if I remove the position attribute altogether, then in IE - I am seeing a "." in front of the "+" sign of the checkbox.

If I make the position attribute: "relative", I get desired behavior in IE but in Chrome it still scrolls out.

Can someone please let me know what should I do?

Comment: Three separate issues should be three separate questions.

Comment: ok, I did as I thought it would be easier to answer. but I have split them now.

Comment: what "checkbox" suppose to when you click on it?

Comment: it is just supposed to add the element to another container. But that is not the problem.

Comment: it doesn't show that, Also, I'm not sure what is the problem, could you explain it more?

Comment: If you scroll to the right and click the check box, you will see the page scrolls left. This is the main problem.

If I make position:relative - it works in IE, but not chrome.

Answer (score 0):

By what your code looks like, it seems you are trying to hide the checkbox and use it's label instead.    If this is the case, then you are going the long way around.

Instead of:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
    left: -1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Simply use:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
```

There is no reason for the checkbox to be viewable at all.

A spot I use this method: http://codepen.io/jacksonrk/pen/myqLOE

Comment: I think my problem is not clear. The issue is not around what happens on click or the appearance of checkbox/label.

Basically, if you see my code in Chrome, and click on a checkbox, I do not want the page to scroll. How can I avoid that?

Comment: ok thanks, it does work. I had copied the above code from another example.